# How to sort a text file by column and keep the original order

Tags: sorting

I have a very large file of data with 15 columns. I need to sort all lines based on a specific column, say column 11. I am using this command in Linux:

```
sort -k11 -d myfile.txt > sortedfile
```

The problem is that the sort command does not preserve the original order of file. For instance, if I have something like this:

```
1 mh3
3 ygb
4 mh3
```

I need to have:

```
1 mh3
4 mh3
3 ygb
```

However, I may get:

```
4 mh3
1 mh3
3 ygb
```

Is there any option to keep the original order or any other commands that I can use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Option `-s` is what you need (equivalent to `--stable` ):

```
sort -k11,11 -d -s myfile.txt > sortedfile
```

The option `-k` works with a range of fields, so you should probably add `,11` as I did above, otherwise the sorting will use keys spanning from column 11 to the end of line (default).

Comment: I have another problem. How I can add column separator to the command? The columns are separated by '\t', but there is 'space' in a same column. The sort is applied to the spaces as well and it changes the definition of columns!

Comment: You can use sort's `-t` flag to specify the separator.   (Ok, a little late to the game, but it might help other readers).

Comment: I did not know that the syntax for `-k` has to be `-k1,1` — I had `-k1` and was getting the wrong behavior, until I stumbled across this answer.