# Sort bash array of one line CSVs based on first column of each CSV in array

Tags: bash

I have a bash array of one line CSVs that I want to put in a numerically increasing order based upon the first column in the CSV.

My array variable looks like this:

```
136,1.1.1.1,1234567890 117,2.2.2.2,0987654321 121,3.3.3.3,6789054321 112,4.4.4.4,1234567809 104,5.5.5.5,0987654312 107,6.6.6.6,6574839201 70.3,7.7.7.7,0987123456 162,8.8.8.8,0123498765 141,9.9.9.9,5432187690 80.3,10.10.10.10,1209568743 142,11.11.11.11,1234567899 92.0,12.12.12.12,0987654322 83.4,13.13.13.13,0987651233 102,14.14.14.14,0912837455 141,15.15.15.15,0912345677
```

I want to be able to format the above array (or any other of the same structure) into this numerical order:

```
70.3,7.7.7.7,0987123456 80.3,10.10.10.10,1209568743 83.4,13.13.13.13,0987651233 92.0,12.12.12.12,0987654322 102,14.14.14.14,0912837455 104,5.5.5.5,0987654312 107,6.6.6.6,6574839201 112,4.4.4.4,1234567809 117,2.2.2.2,0987654321 121,3.3.3.3,6789054321 136,1.1.1.1,1234567890 141,9.9.9.9,5432187690 141,15.15.15.15,0912345677 142,11.11.11.11,1234567899 162,8.8.8.8,0123498765
```

I have tried piping the entire array into the sort command `echo ${array[*]} | sort -k1 -n -t,`, but that doesn't work on single line data sets.

I am aware that I could simply dump the data into a file and use sort, that was the method I was using before, but I need to avoid writing to disk entirely.
My previous approach was with this code (it takes in a multi-line variable of the one line CSVs):

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    ipaddr=$(echo $line | cut -d"," -f1)
    value3=$(echo $line | cut -d"," -f2)
    latency=$(ping -c1 -W5 -4n $ipaddr | grep -o "time=.*" | sed 's/time=//g' | sed 's/ ms//g')
    echo $latency,$ipaddr,$value3 >> /tmp/.sort
done < <(printf '%s\n' "$input_data")
sort -k1 -n -t, /tmp/.sort
```

I can't seem to find anything online about sorting arrays based upon values in each array item.

Does anyone have a clever way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Please post your code where you were dumping it to a file and sorting it. I'm betting you could rewrite it to avoid writing anything to disk, like with pipelines or process substitution (although those might use temporary files under the hood, I don't remember).

Comment: Just added my previous code. In order to sort on the first field (latency) I appended each line of the input variable to the new file and then used the sort command.

Comment: Please make a [mre]. `$input_data` is not defined and it seems like `ping` is not relevant to the problem, plus if I do the same `ping` from my system, I'll probably get a different number. Just post the data.

Comment: `...value3 115...` use `sed` (or `tr`) to substitute `'\n'` for `' '` and then `sort -n`.

Comment: Oh wait, you did post the data? You said it's an array, but there's no array in your code...

Comment: `printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}" | sort -n -t ',' -k1,1` ?

Comment: That works too. Let the old `printf` trick split on whitespace.

Comment: The input data is equivalent to the array snippet I posted above it, but without the numbers appended to the start of each CSV. I didn't include it in the code snippet because the specific values are ephemeral and generated by that piece of code.

Comment: So the data you posted is a mock version of `/tmp/.sort` read into an array? That makes sense, but why are you reading it into an array in the first place? I'm just trying to understand your data structure and how it gets transformed. If it's not an array at all, that's fine, but I want to clarify that.

Comment: Oh, I just understood part of it. Instead of `echo ... >> /tmp/.sort`, you'd do `array+=(...)`.

Comment: The code snippet I posted was how I previously parsed the data, but I am now trying to do it without files using an array. The last line in that while loop I have now replaced with ```output_data+=("$latency,$ipaddr,$value3")```, and the data that is written into ```$output_data``` is what I'm trying to sort. Sorry if I misunderstood what you were asking. Also, I have posted a more accurate data set on the answer below.

Comment: @ehammer lol I just figured that out myself :) Please put the more accurate data in the question.

Comment: @wjandrea Sorry about that. Its updated with better data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data has spaces it in. You can use that to split on spaces leaving you with multiple lines of input with the numeric value first which you can then sort with `sort -n`. You can use `sed` or `tr` or even `printf` (as mentioned by Fravadona) to split the single lines of input.

For example, take your first data and simply use `tr` to translate spaces to newlines and then sort, e.g.

```bash
$ tr ' ' '\n' <<< "136,value1,value2,value3 115,value1,value2,value3 125,value1,value2,value3 111,value1,value2,value3 103,value1,value2,value3 108,value1,value2,value3 70.5,value1,value2,value3 166,value1,value2,value3 142,value1,value2,value3" | 
sort -n
70.5,value1,value2,value3
103,value1,value2,value3
108,value1,value2,value3
111,value1,value2,value3
115,value1,value2,value3
125,value1,value2,value3
136,value1,value2,value3
142,value1,value2,value3
166,value1,value2,value3
```

There are multiple ways to do it, choose the one that fits your needs.

If your `"value1,value2,value3"` are numeric and would interfere with a numeric sort of the entire record, limit the sort to the first field separated with `','`, e.g.

```bash
sort -t, -k1,1n
```

Which will provide a numeric sort based on the first-field only limiting the comparison from the start of field 1 to the end of field 1. Using the data in the comment, you would have:

```
$ tr ' ' '\n' <<< "136,1.1.1.1,1234567890 117,2.2.2.2,0987654321 121,3.3.3.3,6789054321 112,4.4.4.4,1234567809 104,5.5.5.5,0987654312 107,6.6.6.6,6574839201 70.3,7.7.7.7,0987123456 162,8.8.8.8,0123498765 141,9.9.9.9,5432187690 80.3,10.10.10.10,1209568743 142,11.11.11.11,1234567899 92.0,12.12.12.12,0987654322 83.4,13.13.13.13,0987651233 102,14.14.14.14,0912837455 141,15.15.15.15,0912345677" | 
sort -t, -k1,1n
70.3,7.7.7.7,0987123456
80.3,10.10.10.10,1209568743
83.4,13.13.13.13,0987651233
92.0,12.12.12.12,0987654322
102,14.14.14.14,0912837455
104,5.5.5.5,0987654312
107,6.6.6.6,6574839201
112,4.4.4.4,1234567809
117,2.2.2.2,0987654321
121,3.3.3.3,6789054321
136,1.1.1.1,1234567890
141,15.15.15.15,0912345677
141,9.9.9.9,5432187690
142,11.11.11.11,1234567899
162,8.8.8.8,0123498765
```

Let me know if that isn't the desired output you are looking for.

Comment: That seems to work at first, but it appears that the sort command is sorting based on the entire line, so if value1 is numeric, it would contribute to the order. I have attempted to use ```sort -k1 -n -t,``` but it still has lines out of order.

Comment: I used this data set, with values in the second column. ```136,1.1.1.1,1234567890 117,2.2.2.2,0987654321 121,3.3.3.3,6789054321 112,4.4.4.4,1234567809 104,5.5.5.5,0987654312 107,6.6.6.6,6574839201 70.3,7.7.7.7,0987123456 162,8.8.8.8,0123498765 141,9.9.9.9,5432187690 80.3,10.10.10.10,1209568743 142,11.11.11.11,1234567899 92.0,12.12.12.12,0987654322 83.4,13.13.13.13,0987651233 102,14.14.14.14,0912837455 141,15.15.15.15,0912345677```

Comment: Yes, you can limit it wilt the `KEYDEF` `-k1` to limit sorting to the first key. Use `-t ,` to set the field-separator to `','`. There wasn't anything that could be discerned from `"value1,value2,value3:` without knowing what they were.

Comment: Yeah the example data was a bad example. I have tried using ```-k1``` and ```-t ,```, but the sorted output is still incorrect (using the better example data above)

Comment: Give me a sec to look at the data in the comment. I get a perfect sort. I'll update the answer and let you see. You need `-k1n` or `-k1 -n` for numeric.

Comment: The data output you posted is the wrong order (same thing I saw on my end). The lines starting with ```162,``` and ```102,``` are in the wrong position. Its so close to sorted, I initially thought it worked.

Comment: Oh -- I'm getting old, I missed that, give me another sec.

Comment: @ehammer for some reason the `-t,` field-separator wasn't limiting the sort to the first field only. The `-k KEYDEF` spec in `man 1 sort` says that shouldn't happen as it recognizes when `-t` or `-b` are in effect to limit the comparison to the separated field. The KEYDEF allows you to limit from field-character to field-character, so that is another simply way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you don't need to use an array in the first place, just use a pipeline.

Also, your sorting method is a bit off:

- Based on the ordering of the records starting with "141", you want [a **stable** sort](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20612533/4518341).
- From some quick testing on my Ubuntu system in French, the "time=" number is not localized, so specify `LC_ALL=C`. (BTW, it's worth noting that the label *is* localized, e.g. "temps=".)

Here I'll use the processed data in place of `$input_data`, just to show how it'd work:

```
processed_data='136,1.1.1.1,1234567890
117,2.2.2.2,0987654321
121,3.3.3.3,6789054321
112,4.4.4.4,1234567809
104,5.5.5.5,0987654312
107,6.6.6.6,6574839201
70.3,7.7.7.7,0987123456
162,8.8.8.8,0123498765
141,9.9.9.9,5432187690
80.3,10.10.10.10,1209568743
142,11.11.11.11,1234567899
92.0,12.12.12.12,0987654322
83.4,13.13.13.13,0987651233
102,14.14.14.14,0912837455
141,15.15.15.15,0912345677'

printf '%s\n' "$processed_data" |
    while IFS=, read -r latency ipaddr value3
do
    # Actual processing goes here, i.e. `cut` and `ping`.

    echo "$latency,$ipaddr,$value3"
done |
    LC_ALL=C sort -k1 -n -t, -s
```

Output:

```
70.3,7.7.7.7,0987123456
80.3,10.10.10.10,1209568743
83.4,13.13.13.13,0987651233
92.0,12.12.12.12,0987654322
102,14.14.14.14,0912837455
104,5.5.5.5,0987654312
107,6.6.6.6,6574839201
112,4.4.4.4,1234567809
117,2.2.2.2,0987654321
121,3.3.3.3,6789054321
136,1.1.1.1,1234567890
141,9.9.9.9,5432187690
141,15.15.15.15,0912345677
142,11.11.11.11,1234567899
162,8.8.8.8,0123498765
```